# How to call parent method from child model (knockout)

Tags: knockout.js

I think the title is super misleading but the question is simple.

OK, let me put this into perspective - [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/88rafcfk/).

I have three models: BoardViewModel, List, Card

OK, long story short, `list` model creates an array called `cards`.
`self.cards = ko.observableArray(cards);` (line 79)

Knockout in turn exposes `myObservableArray.remove()` as part of `ko.observableArray()`.

This in turn allows me to ditch cards that served their purpose like so
`self.cards.remove(card);` (line 99)

**Q:** Is there any way for me to call remove() from `card` model?
Or do I need to define another function in List model and pass `card` object over in order to be able to make a call identical to the one on line 99?
`self.archive = function (card)` (line 68)

**hint:** click the *edit* link/button to find *Archive* button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand your `createCard` method on the `List` object to handle the creation of all `Card` objects in that `List`:

```
self.createCard = function (id, title, description, contentItemId) {
    if (id) {
        self.cards.push(new Card(id, title, description, contentItemId, self.cards));
    } else {
        var title = $('#textTitle').val().trim();
        if (title.length > 0) {
            var newCard = new Card(-1, title, "", -1, self.cards);
            self.cards.push(newCard);
            // clear data
            $('#textTitle').val('');
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it pushes a references to the `observableArray` holding the `Card`s into the `Card` object.  The card object can then keep hold of this and make use of it:

```
var Card = function(id, title, description, contentItemId, list) {
    var self = this;

    this.containingArray = ko.observable(list);

    /*...*/


    self.archive = function (card) {
        self.containingArray.remove(self);
    };

}
```

However, you then need to update this property when the parent `List` changes when you drag it from one list to another.  You can add another option to the binding to do this:

```
<div class="cards" data-bind="sortable: { data: cards, afterMove: cardMoved }">
```

With a corresponding function in your `List` model

```
self.cardMoved = function(args) {
    args.item.containingArray(args.targetParent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are fine but it seems like you're solving the problem in a confusing way. The whole idea of having a card as a class is that it needs to know nothing about the array in which it is contained (if it is contained within an array).

The knockout preferred way of handling this in the view would be, if you had a button "remove" on your card, to write this in the view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: cards">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="content"> ... </div>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.cards.remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, you can keep your card class separated from its container *and* have an elegant way of handling the removal of a card from its container in this particular view.

Comment: This can work, assuming the HTML is the only place where the card model needs to be able to tell its parent that it should be removed.  What if you want to prompt for confirmation, then remove the card, for example?

Comment: Actually I already have a remove button beside edit link/button in HTML. Which is wired up to make use of function and line 99 to remove the card completely from database and from cards array. But when I archive a card I have database updated appropriately and the only missing bit is removing object from cards array so that users no longer see it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a bit similar to James' but I prefer to pass callbacks into objects, rather than the entire parent list; (and I'd handle card construction differently)

So the card constructor would look like

```
var Card = function (id, title, description, contentItemId, removeCallback) {
    //Rest unchanged
    self.archive = function () {
        removeCallback(self);
    };
}
```

Then, your list would look something like this: (note the change from `cards` to `cardData`)

```
var List = function (id, name, cardData, sortOrder) {
    var self = this;

    function removeCard(card) {
        self.removeCard(card);
    }

    self.cards = ko.observableArray(cardData.map(function (data) {
        //Construct a card object from the provided data
        return new Card(data.id, data.title, data.description, data.contentItemId, removeCard);
    }));
    //Rest unchanged
}
```

And finally, when constructing your list, you'd change each card from

```
new Card(1, "Document all code", "Document all classes, methods and properties in source code.", -1),
```

to

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Document all code",
    description: "Document all classes, methods and properties in source code.",
    contentItemId: -1
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un0u9htv/2/)

Comment: You are most certainly correct. I actually have a database backing for this project that I am working on. So the data arrives in JSON format. Instead of ``var list = function (id, name, cardData, sortOrder)`` I have ``var list = function (item)``. Makes things a bit easier to work with.

Comment: From my understanding I can only pass callbacks to functions that have been declared as ``function func()``? I received an error when I tried to use a function that was declared ``self.removeCard = function (card)``.

Comment: No; you can pass callbacks regardless of how they were declared.  If you declare it as `self.removeCard` though you'll need to pass it as `self.removeCard` and not simply `removeCard`.

Comment: Strange thats exactly how I passed it. I'll try again later.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference of the parent List to the card (extra param in constructor), then:

```
self.archive = function () {
    self.parentList.removeCard(self);
};
```

[*`JSFiddle`*](http://jsfiddle.net/88rafcfk/9/)

You need to handle also parent changes, like @James said.

Comment: It needs to update the `parentList` as it's moved from one list to another in the `sortable` binding